# Improve SQL Server query performance

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I would like to know if there is any tool which will give me the optimized SQL query for which ever query I specify. So that I can improve my DB as well as query performance. I use SQL Server 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a magic wand... you might need to work a little harder than that.

Comment: It's called stackoverflow.com. But make sure to ask nicely

Answer (score 3):

The old Rule of DBs still applies, don't try to optimize sql statements, since the DB query parser will do its own optimizations anyway, instead do right away what we all do in the end:

**Create indexes to increase performance**

Don't get me wrong of course sql queries can be written stupidly and will therefore perform badly, but as long as you created a sensable 'normal' query, the query optimizer will do the rest together with the indexes.

SQL Server will even tell you if a query will clearly benefit from an index when you look at the execution plan. It will even generate the DDL statement to create the index, so all you have to do is copy/paste and run it to have the index your query needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can already watch the execution plan that gives you SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Redgate, they have evaluation versions for most of their products:
[Redgate Website](http://www.red-gate.com)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005 and up comes with a Query Optimizer. This can help, but tools can't really do too much optimization suggesting for you because they don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

You might try taking a look instead at some ways in which *you* can optimize your queries. Here are some links to get you started.

[Tips, Tricks, and Advice from the MS SQL Query Optimization Team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/)

[SQL Server Rules for Optimizing Queries, best practices](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/20/sql-server-rules-for-optimizining-any-query-best-practices-for-query-optimization/)

[Statistics Used by the Query Optimizer in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd535534%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 7.0 / 2000 came with 'index tuning wizard' this functionality has been around for a long time.

I'd reccomend having a look at 'select * from sys.dm_db_missing_index_details'
It tells you which indexes are 'missing', it's trivial to look in that table and then create indexes